# PowerShell problem with sort-object and select-object

Tags: powershell

I am using PowerShell trying to use `Sort-Object` and `Select-Object` to keep (and delete) X number of sub folders (c:\temp\temp_yyyymmdd) ) in a particular folder (c:\temp) . There are several examples out there of this, but I wanted to understand why my code isn't working. I am trying to use Sort-Object to sort the subfolders by creation time (this works) and then use Select-Object -First (I've tried -Last and -Skip as well) to isolate the 2 most recent folders that I want to keep and then delete all others.

In the example folder structure below I would want to keep the 2 most recent and delete the older 3.

> c:\temp
> c:\temp\temp_20211102
> c:\temp\temp_20211124
> c:\temp\temp_20211208
> c:\temp\temp_20220119
> c:\temp\temp_20220120

code is below

```
function Remove-OldBackups
{
    $numberToRetain = 1
    write-host ""
    write-host "now running Remove-OldBackups"

    write-host "AppInstanceRootPath is $AppInstanceRootPath"
    write-host "AppInstanceName is $AppInstanceName (we're excluding this folder)"

    #$itemsToDelete = get-childitem -Path $AppInstanceRootPath -Exclude $AppInstanceName | Select-String -Pattern $AppInstanceName | Sort-Object -Property CreationDate -Descending | Select-Object -last 
    $itemsToDelete = get-childitem -Path $AppInstanceRootPath -Exclude $AppInstanceName | Select-String -Pattern $AppInstanceName | Sort-Object -Property CreationDate -Descending | Select-Object -First $numberToRetain

    write-host ""
    write-host "items to delete are"
    $itemsToDelete
    write-host ""

    write-host ""
    write-host "Now removing old instance backups on $env:computername\$AppInstanceRootPath"

    foreach ($folder in $itemsToDelete)
    {
        write-host "folder to delete is $folder"
        #Get-ChildItem -Directory $folder * -Recurse | Remove-Item
        #Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $folder
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you have put into the question uses `Sort-Object -Property CreationDate -Descending` but `Get-ChildItem` doesn't return a property called `CreationDate` it's `CreationTime` is this a typo in the question?

Comment: What he said ^ and, you can simplify this with a `Where-Object` using the correct property, and filtering by date in regard to what's older than what's specified: `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\MyPath" | Where-Object -Property CreationTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-2)`

Comment: You first exclude `$AppInstanceName` when calling `Get-ChildItem`, but then use `Select-String` to... look for `$AppInstanceName`? What's the big idea?

Comment: Why do you exclude then select-string the same pattern?  Note full paths don't work with exclude.